# "Rejoin all rooms" button on mobile

Tags: feature-request, chat

I know there's one in the room list, but I'd prefer for it to be shown in the menu for all rooms as well (unless it has been explicitly declined in the current session).

Comment: Why would you want to join every room?

Comment: @Unitato it joins only your favorited rooms

Comment: @Unitato No, this option already exists; it's called "rejoin all"/"rejoin all rooms"